# Laravel redirecting when accessing post route directly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I do a post request to a route `calculate-cars` and display an other view with some data I query based on the data I entered in the form I do the post request from, but I want to redirect to the homepage when someone access this route directly.

Unfortunately I keep getting this error:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

my route:

`Route::post('calculate-cars', 'CarsController@calculateCars');`

I know I get this error because I access a post route directly but I try this in my controller method but I still get the same error:

```
if (!$request->isMethod('post')) {
    return redirect()->to('/');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Add another route

```
Route::get('calculate-cars', function () {
    return redirect()->to('/');
});
```

If you'r using Laravel 5.5, you can do it like this:

```
Route::redirect('/calculate-cars', '/', 301);
```

**UPDATE**: 
The method `Route::redirect` will redirect the post route as well, it's not useful in your case.

Just put this in your routes/web.php file:

```
Route::get('calculate-cars', function () {
    return redirect()->to('/');
});
```

Comment: I add `Route::redirect('/calculate-cars', '/', 301);`in my routes file?

Comment: Yes. under the line `Route::post('calculate-cars', 'CarsController@calculateCars');`

Answer (score 2):

You didn't explain why you expect a `POST` request. Do you save calculations to save time (cache)? Only in that case, `POST` is a right decision.

In addition to others: it's important to choose your http methods wisely.

- GET: for READ (no system change)!
- POST: for CREATE
- etc.

Like I said, why did you choose for `POST`? Change only to `GET` if you want to read. MDN has a clear summary about the methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Comment: He is right, this makes little sense if you return to a Post... Typically, you would load your form with a GET request... that form action will POST... however, the page from which the form is gotten is a GET request so when you go back, you go back to loading the form with a GET ... Hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

> but I want to redirect to the homepage when someone access this route
>   directly.

That means when a user does a `GET`

Your route `Route::post('calculate-cars', 'CarsController@calculateCars');`

only allows `POST`

So change it to

`Route::any('calculate-cars', 'CarsController@calculateCars');`

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are trying to **redirect** the user upon **MethodNotAllowedHttpException**

You can use Laravel's Exception Handler for this:

Open `app/Exception/Handler.php` and change `render` method to this:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException)
    {
        return \Redirect::to('/');
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but I am unable to use Exception in render since in function render of Exception handler it uses Throwable.

Comment: I am using Laravel 8

Answer (score 0):

Rename your route to something different and test it again.

For instance

**Route::post('calculate-cars', 'CarsController@calculateCars');**

could be like

**Route::post('calculate-test-cars', 'CarsController@calculateCars');**

I have had cases where changing the route might do the trick. Not sure if it's always like that.

Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try using `any` method in route and place your condition in controller then,

`Route::any('calculate-cars', 'CarsController@calculateCars');`

Hope this will work.